# Remove Gradle default Source Sets

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to run gradle to generate an eclipse project.

I'd like the following structure:

```
project
└── src 
    ├── main 
    │   ├── ...
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── ...
    └── test 
        ├── ...
        ├── ...
        └── ...
```

Here is the relevant part of my `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'main'
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
    }
}
```

It generates this `.classpath`:

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test"/>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
```

This seems to be confusing eclipse. I'd like to remove the default source sets in gradle (I think that's the solution) which will generate a proper `.classpath`.

Comment: How are you creating new gradle project? Why aren't you just going with default(standard) sourceset layout?

Comment: I just don't want the last two class path entries, when I run `gradle elipse`.

Comment: I was unaware of the convention. Is it so disruptive that it requires a good reason?

Comment: For standard layout see section 45.4 here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html Sticking with the standard layout means less wrangling with configuration like you're having to do, and cleaner build files. So unless there is a compelling reason to deviate, it is better to stick to standard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```gradle
sourceSets { 
  main { 
    java { srcDirs = [ 'main' ] } 
  }
  test { 
    java { srcDirs = [ 'test' ] } 
  }
}
```

This overrides the source set property, instead of extending it. You can add more comma-separated directories in square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

As per [SourceDirectorySet documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#setSrcDirs(java.lang.Iterable))

`srcDir` adds a new location to the set, while `setSrcDirs` replaces, and is likely what you're looking for.